# std::string failed requirement error in android studio .cpp files

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrate C++ with Android Studio via NDK but I am facing an error which says follows

```
In instantiation of template class 'std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >' failed requirement '__is_allocator<std::__ndk1::allocator<char>, void, void>::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
```

I can't understand the error and can't find the solution as well.
Below is my code

native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
```

The location of **string** is C:\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\include\c++\v1\string

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            }
        }

    }
    
    ndkVersion '21.0.6113669'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing jobject /*this*/ to just jobject obj ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help .The error persists.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full error message. At the very least it should tell you a line number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above arised due to the placement of the folder .
The NDK was by default placed in the C:/User Name/Android/Sdk/Ndk
The space that between the word User and the word Name made it difficult to locate the ndk folder for the IDE.
After shifting the SDK to another location C:/Android/Sdk the project worked successfully without any errors.